# GCP Debian VM ntp stuck in INIT

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, ntp

I am trying to get NTP working for a Debian 10 VM client machine in GCP.
These are the relevant config lines in /etc/ntp.conf:

```
server metadata.google.internal iburst
server 169.254.169.254 iburst
# Permit all access over the loopback interface.  This could
# be tightened as well, but to do so would effect some of
# the administrative functions.
restrict 10.10.184.9 # my machine's IP
restrict ::1
```

Nothing I do seems to resolve this issue:

```
ansible@node:~$ sudo ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 metadata.google .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
ansible@liproj-prod-ct-cloudapp-admin:~$
```

I can ping the NTP server from this host.  Not sure what I can try next?

Comment: Please show all of your config.  It's likely that something in there is preventing you from querying it.  It's best to keep the NTP config as close to the Debian defaults as possible and just add the Google NTP server to the existing config.

Comment: Without seeing your config, I'd guess that you've removed `restrict source notrap nomodify noquery` from the default config, and adding it back would fix things.